# Amazon Fatal Error

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services

I am using the amazon.com products API. The call is `GetMatchingProductForId`. When I type as single value into the call, it works. When I input a large file to my program it works, but I occasionally get a fatal error:

```
Fatal Error:Can Only Throw Objects in J:/filepath/client.php on line 1003.
```

I have no idea what the possible error is. When i contacted amazon developer support they said they would investigate the issue. 
The problem could possibly be the user input because I ran my program yesterday and was able to get 2797 files in response, but eventually received the same error. When i ran my program for the first time during testing, there was no problem at all. If anyone has knowledge of this error and could explain just the error, I would greatly appreciate it.

Client.php lines 992 - 1004:

```
 for (;;) {
   $response = $this->_httpPost($parameters);
   $status = $response['Status'];
   if ($status == 200) {
       return array('ResponseBody' => $response['ResponseBody'],
      'ResponseHeaderMetadata' => $response['ResponseHeaderMetadata']);
   }
   if ($status == 500 && $this->_pauseOnRetry(++$retries)) {
       continue;
   }
   throw $this->_reportAnyErrors($response['ResponseBody'],
   $status, $response['ResponseHeaderMetadata']);
 }
```

I did not edit any of this code. This came from `developer.amazonservices.com`

`_reportAnyErrors` Function :

```
private function _reportAnyErrors($responseBody, $status, $responseHeaderMetadata, Exception $e =  null)
{
    $exProps = array();
    $exProps["StatusCode"] = $status;
    $exProps["ResponseHeaderMetadata"] = $responseHeaderMetadata;

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);  // Silence XML parsing errors
    $xmlBody = simplexml_load_string($responseBody);

    if ($xmlBody !== false) {  // Check XML loaded without errors
        $exProps["XML"] = $responseBody;
        $exProps["ErrorCode"] = $xmlBody->Error->Code;
        $exProps["Message"] = $xmlBody->Error->Message;
        $exProps["ErrorType"] = !empty($xmlBody->Error->Type) ? $xmlBody->Error->Type : "Unknown";
        $exProps["RequestId"] = !empty($xmlBody->RequestID) ? $xmlBody->RequestID : $xmlBody->RequestId; // 'd' in RequestId is sometimes capitalized
    } else { // We got bad XML in response, just throw a generic exception
        $exProps["Message"] = "Internal Error";
        continue;
    }
}
```

Values :

```
20373001862
20373002678
20373002685
20373002937
20373003002
20373003583
20373003644
20373003651
20373003675
20373003682
20373003781 
20373003811
20373003828
20373003835
20373003842
20373003859
20373003866
20373003873
20373003880
20373003897
20373003903
20373005006
```

With these values it crashed on the third file which would be the 20th value.

Comment: You need to provide some code. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and update your question

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your client.php code, but it could be due to amazon limiting the number of requests you can make. See the HTTP response headers of the requests for your quota.

Comment: I use `sleep(2)` to wait. I will update the question with some client.php code.

Comment: Can you show the `_reportAnyErrors()` function?

Comment: Updated. Thank you for taking a look at this.

Comment: @Bono When i upload a different file it is able to work, but with this specific file, it doesn't work. I keep attempting with different data. sometimes it works fully, sometimes it does not.

Comment: Do you perhaps know with which specific data it crashes? Could you show some of the values that work, and some that don't work?

My hunch is that maybe you're passing a value that it can't work with. It then tries to throw an exception of some kind, but can't because the value doesn't allow it (since aparently, it's not an object).

Comment: It comes at random times. for example: when i run a scan on the products i will get some responses. sometimes 2797 of them and then it will just stop. last night during testing this was the problem. I will post some data that it could possibly crash on.

Comment: @Bono I updated the values.

Comment: @Robert I'm afraid I don't have enough knowledge of the amazon services to determine where an error might be at play. Hopefully developer support will be able to come up with something. Maybe someone else will run in to the question with a bit more knowledge about the subject. Perhaps it's what Kennedy said and they're just limiting the amount of requests. If you try to manually enter the failing value, do you get a correct response or another failure? Perhaps it has to do with the specific product or something :/

Comment: @Bono I am attempting to run another file right now, i will let you know if there is an error. With this file I was able to get the full request. Hopefully developer support answers. Thanks for your time though.